# Center plotly title by default

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly figure which I center the title using -

```
fig.update_layout(
            title={
            'text' : title,
            'x':0.5,
            'xanchor': 'center'
        })
```

I have multiple graphs and I add this to every one of them. I wonder if I can define it in advance, e.g using config object or settings, and not do it for every chart.

Comment: Yeah,  It's pretty silly to me that this is not the default behavior.

Answer (score 35):

This works with me easily:

```
fig.update_layout(title_text='write a title here', title_x=0.5)
```

Comment: This causes my title to start at the center point instead of centered at the center point. 
[-----title-] instead of  [----title----]

Answer (score 7):

you need to add the following parameters for the "y axis" to your dict as the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/#align-plot-title) mentions it:

```
title = {
         'text': "Plot Title",
         'y':0.9, # new
         'x':0.5,
         'xanchor': 'center',
         'yanchor': 'top' # new
        }
```

Comment: But this also just does it to one graph instance, right?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you will have to update each figure. Also, you could create a global dictionary and call it with each plot.